# How I have to save a copy of my App project on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to delete Android Studio from my computer and reinstall it.

To save my project I have only to copy the project in Users\AndroidStudioProjects\myappfolder?

After reinstall Android Studio if I have this folder in my Hardisk is it enough? Do I have to do something more??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For my projects that I build in Android Studio, I like to use an external source control such as Git or Bitbucket. I commit my source code to those repositories, and then I can install them to any computer in the future - it is a good way to back them up. Use the VCS menu in Android Studio to set it up.